# NextJs Build Error Collecting Page Data In NextAuth API File

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, vercel, next.js13, next-auth

I'm using NextAuth in a NextJS application and everything is working as expected when I run the application. However during the build process it is throwing an error. The error message is:

```
> Build error occurred
Error: Collecting page data for [object Object] is still timing out after 2 attempts.
```

I can tell that this error is coming from the file `/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts`

I believe that the issue is stemming from a top-level await that I am using to grab secrets from AWS Secrets Manager in the file. The api code is as follows:

```js
const cognito = await getSecret<Cognito>(process.env.COGNITO_SECRET);
const azure = await getSecret<Azure>(process.env.AZURE_AD_SECRET);

const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CognitoProvider({
      clientId: cognito.cognitoClientId,
      clientSecret: cognito.cognitoClientSecret,
      issuer: cognito.cognitoIssuer,
    }),
    AzureProvider({
      clientId: azure.client_id,
      clientSecret: azure.client_secret,
      tenantId: azure.tenant_id,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async redirect({ baseUrl }) {
      return baseUrl;
    },
  },
  secret: 'random',
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

I've changed the timeout seconds in the next.config.js file like so:

```
module.exports = {
  staticPageGenerationTimeout: 1000
}
```

And it just hangs in the console saying `- info Collecting page data ...`

Are the top level awaits the issue here or is there something that I am missing?